# Query value if it is not zero using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Using EF, I want to query an integer, but if the value is 0, I don't want to do the query.

```
rentalContext.Apartments
    .Include(a => a.ApartmentType)
    .Include(a => a.Files)
    .Include(a => a.Address)
    .Where(a => some other search conditions &&
        (filters.CityId != 0 && a.Address.CityObject.Id == filters.CityId))
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Created);
```

It works fine if `CityId` isn't 0, but if it is zero, then it returns 0 objects in the list. Is this not the way you are supposed to do this?

Comment: `filters.CityId != 0 && ` should be `filters.CityId == 0 || ` ([De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it will check the second condition only if `filters.CityId == 0` is false.

```
rentalContext.Apartments
    .Include(a => a.ApartmentType)
    .Include(a => a.Files)
    .Include(a => a.Address)
    .Where(a => some other search conditions &&
         (filters.CityId == 0 || a.Address.CityObject.Id == filters.CityId))
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Created)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @DanielGustafsson updated the answer. I misunderstood what you meant